# React navbar component causing render to fail

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting up a react project and I'm trying to add a simple Navbar.

My App.js looks like this

```js
import React, { Component, Navbar } from "react";
import TheNav from "./Components/Nav.js";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Navbar />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

My index.js looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

When I run this, the browser shouts this at me:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't export a `Navbar` component. Use your own `TheNav` instead.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TheNav from "./Components/Nav.js";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <TheNav />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks! I used my own Nav component and then imported react-bootstrap. Everything is working smoothly